# getting value in mongoDB by key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how can i get the value of android for example from the following collection named "appVersions"

```
_id:5e2973985874e60017da3905
android:9
ios:1
foodTable:1
__v:0
```

Comment: `db.appVersions.findOne({_id:"5e2973985874e60017da3905"}).android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `db.appVersions.findOne("5e2973985874e60017da3905")`. That will return a document containing an `android` property.

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.find( {"_id": ObjectId("5e2973985874e60017da3905")} )
```